# HLK Strong Name Installation failed

Tags: strongname

There is a strong name validation failure when I install the prerelease HLK controller.
(21301.1000.210123-1645.rs_prerelease_amd64fre_HLK.iso)

Error log:

> MSI (s) (8C:BC) [18:23:51:383]: Note: 1: 1708  MSI (s) (8C:BC)
> [18:23:51:383]: Product: HLK Strong Name PreCondition Check --
> Installation failed.
>
> MSI (s) (8C:BC) [18:23:51:399]: Windows Installer installed the
> product. Product Name: HLK Strong Name PreCondition Check. Product
> Version: 10.1.21301.1000. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer:
> Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 1603.
>
> MSI (s) (8C:BC) [18:23:51:399]: Deferring clean up of packages/files,
> if any exist MSI (s) (8C:BC) [18:23:51:399]: MainEngineThread is
> returning 1603 MSI (s) (8C:80) [18:23:51:399]: RESTART MANAGER:
> Session closed. MSI (s) (8C:80) [18:23:51:399]: No System Restore
> sequence number for this installation.

Answer (score 0):

Run commands as Administrator.

Following steps to manually clear and add workable registry value

```
reg DELETE "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification" /f 
reg ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification\*,*" /f 

reg DELETE "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification" /f 
reg ADD "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification\*,*" /f
```